# How to print the result of a google search

Tags: python, google-chrome, search, chatbot

I am trying to create a simple chat bot in python, I want the bot to search for something on google and return the result as text.

Example:
(input) What is the height of the Eiffel Tower
(output) 300 m, 330 m to tip

I want something like this.

Answer (score 0):

#### Install some tools

- pip install googlesearch-python
- pip install beautifulsoup4
- pip install requests

#### Use beautifulsoup to extract the text from the HTML response

```
from googlesearch import search
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def search_google(query):
    url = list(search(query, num_results=1))[0]
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    result = soup.get_text()
    return result


while True:
    query = input("What would you like to search for on Google? ")
    result = search_google(query)
    print(result)
```

#### Trim the response to show lines of sufficient length to be potentially interesting

```
from googlesearch import search
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def search_google(query):
    url = list(search(query, num_results=1))[0]
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    result = soup.get_text()
    return result


query = "height of Eiffel tower"
result = search_google(query)

MINIMUM_INTERESTING_LENGTH = 30
interesting_lines = [line for line in result.split("\n") if len(line)>30]

interesting_lines
```

#### Example output:

[image]

Comment: I get an error when trying it

Comment: @TheDiamondCreeper, I got the error too, but when I replaced `num_results` with `num` it worked.

Comment: Tried it again and I still get an error

Comment: While it is sad to hear that you are getting an error, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to help you if you don't tell us what the error is. This is a programming website rather than a mind-reading society.